# substituting variables in BEGIN push @INC

Tags: perl, module, directory

So instead of wanting to put

```
BEGIN {push @INC , '/folder1', '/folder2', '/folder3'}
```

to find my module. 
I want to be able to put a variable instead such as this.

```
my $test = '/folder1';
BEGIN {push @INC , $test, '/folder2', '/folder3'}
```

No matter what I do it still wont find the module I want.

Comment: nothing else just that.

Comment: The BEGIN block executes before your variable is defined. Take a look at [`perldoc BEGIN`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END)

Comment: Well I do need the variable for later down the road. I just need to know if this works. Is there a way for me to define my variable before the BEGIN block?

Comment: `use constant TEST => '/folder1';` would also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `BEGIN` executes during parsing of the code, so it would be executed before a variable assignment outside of it occurs.

The solution is to do the assignment inside the `BEGIN` block:

```
my $test;
BEGIN {
    $test = "/some/path";
}
use lib $test, "/path2", "path3";
```

The `use lib …` is preferable to `unshift @INC, …`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually manipulating `@INC`, I suggest that you use [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html):

```
use lib '/folder2', '/folder3';
```

Also, [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) and [`BEGIN`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) blocks are executed as soon as possible, so if you want to include a variable in one, it must be initialized in a `BEGIN` block:

```
our $test;
BEGIN {
     $test = "/some/path";
}
use lib $test, '/folder2', '/folder3';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `BEGIN` statement runs before anything else runs -- even if the BEGIN statement appears later in the program. Variables you're using must also appear inside the `BEGIN`. Any variables declared with `my` will be out of scope once the `BEGIN` statement ends.

```
BEGIN {
     my $test = '/folder1';
     push @INC, $test, '/folder2', '/folder3';
}
```

I'm not sure what this is buying you. You still need to modify the program.  You may want to `use lib;`:

```
use lib qw(/folder1);
use lib qw(/folder2 /folder3);
# use lib qw(/folder4);   # Don't use
```